# Reading a serial port in python with unknown data length

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to read data from a pic32 microcontroller configured as a serial port.

The pic32 sends "binary" data variable in length (14 to 26 bytes long). I want to read in the data and separate the bits then convert them to their decimal equivalent.

```
import serial
import csv

#open the configuartion file
with open('config.txt') as configFile:
   #save the config parameters to an array called parameters
   parameters = configFile.read().split()

#Function to Initialize the Serial Port
def init_serial():
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.port = 'COM7'
    ser.timeout = 10
    ser.open()
    if ser.isOpen():
        print ('Open: ' + ser.portstr)

#call the serial initilization function
init_serial()

#writes the lines from the config file to the serial port
counter = 0
while counter<4:
    ser.write(chr(int(parameters[counter])).encode('utf-8') + chr(int(parameters[counter+1])).encode('utf-8'))
    counter = counter + 2

#opens the csv file to append to 
resultsFile = open('results.csv', 'wt')

#writes the titles of the four columns to the csv file
resultsFile.write("{} {} {} {}\n".format('ChannelAI', 'ChannelAQ', 'ChannelBI', 'ChannelBQ')) 


count=0
while count < 10:    

    #read from serial port
    incoming = ser.read(26)

    #decodes incoming bytes to a string
    incoming = incoming.decode('cp1252')


    #will select element 4, 5 & 6 from incoming data
    channelAIstr = incoming[4:6]
    #converts slected elements to an integer
    channelAI=int(channelAIstr, 16)

    channelAQstr = incoming[7:10]
    #channelAQ=int(channelAQstr, 16)

    channelBIstr = incoming[10:13]
    #channelBI=int(channelBIstr, 16)

    channelBQstr = incoming[13:16]
    #channelBQ=int(channelBQstr, 16)

    #writes to csv file
    resultsFile.write("{} {} {} {}\n".format(str(channelAI), str(channelAQ), str(channelBI), str(channelBQ)))             

    count = count + 1

#close the file to save memory
resultsFile.close()
```

I am having some trouble properly reading and converting the bits from the serial port. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

I know I am reading the serial port correctly and am getting data that looks something like this "\x00\x7f\x7f" as an example. I then want to convert this 3 byte long string to an integer.

Comment: If you are getting `\x00\x7f\x7f`, what do you expect instead? Resp., what does these data mean?

In other words, what does your (14 or 26 or whatever bytes long) data record consist of?

Comment: 1-`incoming = incoming.decode('cp1252')` don't need because incoming data is `ASCII`. 2- you can't receive right data if haven't any one **END** delimiter.

Comment: @dsgdfg Depends - if you have length information in the packet or the length is always the same and you have some other means of synchronization, it's fine as well. E. g., what's `incoming[0:4]` here?

Comment: He is `ser.write(chr(int(parameters[counter])).encode('utf-8') + chr(int(parameters[counter+1])).encode('utf-8'))` twist, so rape serial port, which incoming first(**FIFO**), where a query where matched answer? Who clear `serial buffer`? He send query and try opening file, what is timeout exception ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you determine if the data is 14 or 26 bytes long or anything in-between.

In all cases, you might want to use a wrapper class which wraps the IO.

On every request of data, you can have the wrapper either read a certain number of bytes or all bytes which are available, until you have enough to decode. Then the wrapper decodes them and returns them as a tuple.

This is a first guess about how you can proceed; I do not see where exactly you are having trouble in your code.

---

But this is only syntactig sugar and for a more advanced state of your program.

For the start, let's locate the more obvious things: You seem to be ripping the data apart in a wrong way. Your code

```
#will select element 4, 5 & 6 from incoming data
channelAIstr = incoming[4:6]
```

does not fit to each other: indexing `[4:6]` means 4 inclusive to 6 exclusive. If you really want 4, 5 and 6, you have to write `[4:7]`.

The next step is to convert this into an integer. If you have `\x00\x7f\x7f`, this can mean a lot of things:

- If it is a 24 bit integer, it can be little or big endian. In the first case, it is `0x7F7F00`, in the second case it is `0x007F7F`.

  These cases can be dealt with

  ```
  >>> a='\x00\x7f\x7f'
  >>> import struct
  >>> struct.unpack("<I", a+"\x00")[0]
  8355584
  >>> 0x7f7f00
  8355584
  >>> struct.unpack(">I", "\x00"+a)[0]
  32639
  >>> 0x7f7f
  32639
  ```
- If it is a different kind of data format (maybe some floating point?), you have to be more verbose what these data mean.

So, if I am right about the integer solution, just do any of

```
channelAI = struct.unpack(">I", "\x00" + channelAIstr)[0]
channelAI = struct.unpack("<I", channelAIstr + "\x00")[0]
```